# Need help creating custom collection view properly

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

Okay, so the green squares will be images, the size of the row for example like below would be based on the image size to determine how it would look.

I am unsure how to get it 3 rows, and all together like that. I have tried setting it up by using the `insetForSectionAtIndex` and the `insetForSectionAtIndex` but it just doesn't look right. I have attached my code, and the expected result below:

Code:

```
    class Random : UIViewController, UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDataSource{
    var random = [1, 1, 1, 1, 1]
    override func viewDidLoad() {

    }

    func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier("YoutubeResponsiveCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! UICollectionViewCell

        return cell
    }

    func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
        /*Youtube Video selected*/
    }

    func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 3
    }

    func numberOfSectionsInCollectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView) -> Int {
        return 2
    }
}

class XplainNavigationController : UINavigationController{

}

extension Random : UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout{

    func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView,
        layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout,
        sizeForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGSize {
            var cellSizing : CGSize = UIImage(named: "imageHere")!.size
                    return cellSizing

    }

    func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView,
        layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout,
        insetForSectionAtIndex section: Int) -> UIEdgeInsets {
            return UIEdgeInsetsZero /*Spacing for each video.*/
    }

    func randomInt(min: Int, max:Int) -> Int {
        return min + Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(max - min + 1)))
    }

}
```

Expected result:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/JEgjE.png

Comment: If someone could fix the formatting please, thanks! :)

Comment: Sorry if this seems vague, I can't figure out how to word it exactly.